# Find Word and space to first letter from right and left

Tags: php, regex

I have lines like that

```
Tiamat X (STEAM): WL0CN-VJ62Z-UZAXN-VJ62Z-A5NFF
```

and i want to replace
word STEAM and space from left and right first letters
X (STEAM): W
so in the end i want to have something like this

```
Tiamat X====WL0CN-VJ62Z-UZAXN-VJ62Z-A5NFF
```

flavor - pcre(php)

maybe someone could help me:
sample link:

https://regex101.com/r/cR6aX4/5

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want this:

```
$s = preg_replace('/\W*STEAM\W*/', '====', $s);
```

This would replace `STEAM` with `====` and remove everything around until the previous and following words.